# How do I create objects behind code and display it in the View?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply the MVVM pattern when I want to display dynamic amount of images in the View from the ViewModel.

I have a array of Images in the ViewModel and I want to display it in the view.

How do I display it in the View the best way.

Comment: Use an ObservableCollection<T> in your ViewModel and bind this to your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ItemsControl, bind the ItemsSource to your image list, and then add DataTemplate to your ItemsControl that takes care of the "displaying actual image" part.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="siteView" >
    <Image Source="{Binding _Source}" />
 </DataTemplate>

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource siteView}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YOURIMAGELIST"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of MVVM  in wpf is The DataContext of View Binding The ViewModel.